How to make my Telegram bot stop working at 16:15 and not work on Fridays?
I have a Telegram bot written in Python using the Telethon library. The bot is supposed to function from 10:00 to 16:15 from Saturday to Thursday, and it should be completely inactive on Fridays. However, I'm having trouble getting the bot to stop exactly at 16:15. The bot currently doesn't stop correctly at the specified time.
Here's the relevant part of my code:
import logging
import re
import random
import jdatetime
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import asyncio
import pytz

# API information

api_id =
api_hash = ''
phone_number = ''
channel_id = '@DolarRates'
group_usernames = \['@gheymateTehran2', '@DOLARRATE1', '@gheymateTehran'\]  # Group usernames

# New channel information

new_channel_id = 'https://t.me/Akhbargeymat'
target_channel_id = '@DolarRates'

# Logging settings

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Proxy settings (if needed)

proxy = None  # ('socks5', '127.0.0.1', 9050)  # Example for SOCKS5 proxy

# Create a Telegram client with proxy settings

client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash, proxy=proxy)

# Lock for managing message sending

send_lock = asyncio.Lock()

# Variable for storing the time of the last sent message

last_sent_time = datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=pytz.UTC)

# Global variable to store the new dollar rate

global_new_number_str = "نامشخص"  # Initial value

# Variable for bot running status

is_running = False

# Function to get Tehran time

def tehran_time():
tehran_tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Tehran')
return datetime.now(tehran_tz)

async def send_message_to_channel(message):
try:
logger.info(f"Sending message to channel: {message}")
await client.send_message(channel_id, message)
except Exception as e:
logger.error(f"Failed to send message: {e}")

def get_persian_date():
today = jdatetime.date.today()
return today.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')

async def process_message_text(text):
global last_sent_time, global_new_number_str
current_time = tehran_time()

    async with send_lock:
        if (current_time - last_sent_time).total_seconds() < 60:
            logger.info("Skipping message send due to time limit.")
            return None
    
        # Find the first 5-digit number in the text
        match = re.search(r'\b\d{2},\d{3}\b', text)
        if match:
            # Extract the number
            original_number = match.group()
            # Remove the comma and convert to an integer
            number = int(original_number.replace(',', ''))
            # Decrease the number by 50
            new_number = number - 50
            # Format the new number as a string with commas
            new_number_str = f'{new_number:,}'
            
            # Store the new number in the global variable
            global_new_number_str = new_number_str
            
            # Create the output message
            processed_text = f"""
    ✨ #نرخ_دلار
    
     تاریخ: {get_persian_date()}
    
     #دلار سبزه : {new_number_str} تومان
    
     بروزترین قیمت‌ها رو همین حالا مشاهده کنید.
    
     کانال قیمت #دلار تهران 
    @DolarRates
            """
            last_sent_time = current_time
            return processed_text.strip()
        else:
            logger.error("No 5-digit number found in the text.")
            return None

# Function to process messages from the new channel

def process_new_channel_message(text):
\# Remove unwanted parts
text = re.sub(r'دلار آمريکا.*?\\n', '', text)
text = re.sub(r'⏰ساعت.*?\\n', '', text)
text = re.sub(r'✅ @Akhbargeymat', '', text)
text = re.sub(r'✅ .*?\\n', '', text)
text = text.replace('', '')
text = text.replace('✅', '')  # Remove ✅
text = text.replace('*\*\*\*', '')  # Remove \*\*\*\*

    # Replace flags
    text = text.replace('يورو', ' يورو')
    text = text.replace('پوند انگليس', ' پوند انگليس')
    text = text.replace('درهم امارات', ' درهم امارات')
    text = text.replace('يوآن چين', ' يوآن چين')
    text = text.replace('لير ترکيه', ' لير ترکيه')
    text = text.replace('دینار کویت', ' دینار کویت')
    
    text = text.replace('', '')
    text = text.replace('@Akhbargeymat', '')
    
    # Align text to the right
    lines = text.split('\n')
    aligned_text = '\n'.join(line.strip() for line in lines if line.strip())
    
    # Add new text
    additional_text = """

 بروزترین قیمت‌ها رو همین حالا مشاهده کنید.

 کانال قیمت #دلار تهران 
@DolarRates
"""
return aligned_text.strip() + '\\n\\n' + additional_text.strip()

# Function to read the latest posts from groups and send the newest message every minute

async def read_latest_posts():
while is_running:
for group_username in group_usernames:
try:
logger.info(f"Reading latest post from {group_username}")
messages = await client.get_messages(group_username, limit=1)
if messages:
latest_message = messages\[0\]
processed_text = await process_message_text(latest_message.text)
if processed_text:
logger.info(f"Latest post fetched from {group_username}: {processed_text}")
await send_message_to_channel(processed_text)
except Exception as e:
logger.error(f"Failed to read latest post from {group_username}: {e}")
await asyncio.sleep(60)  # Wait one minute

# Function to read and forward messages from the new channel every 40 minutes without time limits

async def read_and_forward_from_new_channel():
while is_running:
try:
logger.info(f"Reading latest post from {new_channel_id}")
messages = await client.get_messages(new_channel_id, limit=1)
if messages:
latest_message = messages\[0\]
processed_text = process_new_channel_message(latest_message.text)
if processed_text:
logger.info(f"Latest post fetched from {new_channel_id}: {processed_text}")
await send_message_to_channel(processed_text)
await asyncio.sleep(2400)  # Wait 40 minutes
except Exception as e:
logger.error(f"Failed to read and forward from new channel: {e}")

# Handler for new messages

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=group_usernames))
async def handler(event):
if is_running:
try:
processed_text = await process_message_text(event.message.text)
if processed_text:
logger.info(f"New message received from {event.chat.username}: {processed_text}")
await send_message_to_channel(processed_text)
except Exception as e:
logger.error(f"Failed to handle new message from {event.chat.username}: {e}")

# Send greeting and farewell messages

async def send_greeting_messages():
while is_running:
now = tehran_time()
if now.hour == 10 and now.minute == 0:
await send_message_to_channel("به نام خدا")
elif now.hour == 19 and now.minute == 0:
await send_message_to_channel("به امید دیدار")
await asyncio.sleep(60)  # Check every minute

# Send automatic messages every 5 to 8 minutes

async def automated_posting():
while is_running:
tehran_current_time = tehran_time().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
special_message = f"""
✨ #نرخ\_دلار

 تاریخ: {get_persian_date()}

مـعامله انجام شد✅

 #دلار سبزه : {global_new_number_str} تومان

 بروزترین قیمت‌ها رو همین حالا مشاهده کنید.

 کانال قیمت #دلار تهران 
@DolarRates
"""
await send_message_to_channel(special_message.strip())
await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(300, 480))  # Wait between 5 to 8 minutes

# `Function to stop the bot's activities`

`async def shutdown_bot():`
`global is_running`
`is_running = False`
`logger.info("Bot activities have been stopped.")`

`async def main():`
`global is_running`
`logger.info("Starting client...")`
`try:`
`await client.start(phone_number)`
`except Exception as e:`
`logger.error(f"Failed to start client: {e}")`
`else:`
`logger.info("Client started.")`
`while True:`
`now = tehran_time`()

            # Check the time and day to start and stop the bot
            if now.weekday() != 4 and (10 <= now.hour < 16 or (now.hour == 16 and now.minute < 15)):
                if not is_running:
                    is_running = True
                    logger.info("Bot is starting its activities.")
                    await asyncio.gather(
                        send_greeting_messages(), 
                        automated_posting(),
                        read_and_forward_from_new_channel(),
                        read_latest_posts()
                    )
            else:
                if is_running:
                    await shutdown_bot()
                logger.info("Bot is out of working hours or it's Friday.")
                await asyncio.sleep(60)  # Check every minute to start activities

`if `__`name`__` == "`__`main`__`":`
`logger.info("Running main...")`
`client.loop.run_until_complete(main())`
`client.run_until_disconnected()`

I have tried to make the bot work from 10:00 to 16:15 from Saturday to Thursday and stop exactly at 16:15. However, it doesn't stop as expected. Could anyone help me identify what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you in advance for your help!

Please properly format your code (tabs/newlines): See How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML? for help.

Any one can help

You're doing a strategic mistake: You can't take the code and run it, which is what a [mcve] is supposed to provide. Also, the info you provide is contradicting, since you tagged this with two Python versions. Please, as a new user, please take the [tour] and read [ask].
